# Does calling methods in a return statement cause stack to overflow in Java?

Tags: java

I heard that when I call a method the local variables are saved in the stack area of a memory so if I use a code like this:

```
class aClass{
   public int val;
   public int dosth(int a){
      val++;
      int localVariable = val;
      if(val > 100){
         return 0;
      }
      return dosth(a);
   }
}
```

will this cause all the localVariables to be stacked until it meets the

```
return 0;
```

statement???

Comment: The implementation is free to do whatever it likes. They may or may not all exist.

Comment: It should eventually cause a stack overflow, just when depends on the JVM implementation and the environment. If might be several thousand entries (or even more) before the stack is full (most probably the call stack).

Comment: If you ran your program you would know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster is using SO as a substitute for compiling and running a program.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It’s a very good question with a nontrivial answer. @Raedwald No, compiling this code won’t answer the question: it can only give an answer about *one specific implementation* of the compiler/runtime for *one specific piece of code*. Clearly the OP is interested in a more general answer. The answer, incidentally, isn’t trivial and so far the existing answers aren’t quite on the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed what’s happening. You’ve given a succinct description of the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Now, this means that every function call grows the stack. Usually this isn’t a problem because (despite what one may think) calls are never nested very deeply. So the stack usually doesn’t become very large.

This changes once functions start recursively calling themselves: suddenly, stack size could quickly grow by a large amount (depending on your data). This is why care needs to be taken when using recursion to solve problems.

Now, the code you’ve shown is a special case: the recursive call is the last thing that happens inside the method. After that, all we do is return. This special form is known as [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Tail recursion has the nice property of being computationally equivalent to iteration, and in principle tail recursive code can be automatically transformed into iterative code. This means that we can write elegant code and the compiler transforms it for us into code that won’t overflow the stack, regardless of the input we throw at it.

This feature is heavily exploited in functional programming languages, many of which do not have a regular “for” or “loop” instruction, and rely exclusively on recursion instead.

The (official) Java compiler, and Java runtime, by contrast, [do not optimise tail recursion and tail calls](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272061/2366) (so far; this may change in the future). As a consequence, your code will eventually overflow the stack. How fast this happens depends on your particular runtime environment (in particular, it depends on the allocated stack size; you can control this via the `java` command line option [`-Xss`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp999540)). 100 recursive calls won’t be enough to overflow the stack though: a few 1000s are usually necessary at least.

Answer (score 1):

The standard java JVM does not optimize endrecursive calls so you will build up a stack (that could overflow) with that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In all the current JVM implementations I know of, the following will be stored on a stack

- The argument `a`
- The local variable `localVariable`

In fact you can try changing the method above to

```
  public int dosth(int a){
      return dosth(a);
  }
```

You are very likely to get a StackOverflowException eventually.
The more data you store in the local variables, the sooner the exception will occur.

In languages that run on JVM but optimize for [tail-end-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), you will not see a StackOverflowException. In fact future versions of JVM just might do. In that case, the procedure above will turn into a while (true) loop, so don't count on this being true in the future.

Answer (score 0):

With each method invocation, it will be pushed into a stack with all it local variables. However you should not worry too much about the local variables. (*Even though allocating large amount of memory for each stack does quicken a StackOverflow to occur*)

You should ensure, when you implements a recursive method, the terminating condition can be reached and the methods shall return to the point of calling soonest when there is no point making another recursive call.

If you are just making conventional method calling, it is very unlikely you will get hit by **StackOverflowException** as the threshold for number of stacks to be pushed is rather high (not fixed, but you can have up to 100,000 stacks before it overflows). (The limit can be adjusted).

What you should worry is making an infinite recursive call. Which will definitely cause a **StackOverFlowException**.

---

> Does calling methods in a return statement cause stack to overflow in Java?

What you have is a **tail-recursion** and there is ***no such thing*** as "a tail-recursion is bad, it definitely cause StackOverFlow problems". Tail-recursion can be useful in certain situations, just that sometimes you could replace a tail-recursion with a loop which can enhance some performance.

You can run your codes, you will realise it will not hit a StackOverFlowException.

Comment: I’ve never heard anybody claim that “tail recursion is bad”, if anything the contrary. The whole paragraph is confusing.